# Android: Instantiate a Handler in a TimerTask within a Service

Tags: android, android-service

I'm trying to use a service to make a regular call to my API. The asynchronous class I use to make external HTTP calls returns information to a handler which is passed in.

A simplified version below dies on the line where the Handler is instantiated (without a stack trace). Any idea why? Is there a better way I should be doing this?

```
package com.fred.services;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class NotificationService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "com.fred.services NotificationService";

    public long delay = 0;
    public long period_in_minutes = 10;
    public long period = 1000*60*period_in_minutes;

    private Timer timer = null;
    private TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Handler h;
            Log.i(TAG, "now you see it");
            h = new Handler();
            Log.i(TAG, "now you don't");
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        if (timer == null) startservice();
    }

    private void startservice() {
        if (timer == null) timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, delay, period);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better way I should be doing this?

Use `AlarmManager` and an `IntentService`. This allows your code to stay out of memory except during the moments when it is actually adding value to the user (i.e., accessing  your Web service).

Comment: Thanks, this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example has a link to your explanation and an example.